# Error while publishing in Android market

Tags: android, google-play

I am an Android developer. In part of my job I have to upload a new version of our application daily.

The problem is for nearly three to four weeks I get following error at every time when I try to upload in market.

```
The server could not process your apk. Try again.
```

After retrying for nearly 20 times the application is uploading. Can any one pls explain what's happening and whether the problem is mine or in android market.... Pls provide me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sniper

Comment: i think android support is best place for this.

Comment: Seems to be a general bug in the market today.

Comment: Check here, see dates of posts
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the probelm was occured due to lots of different applications trying to upload in same time. Try upoading in different time.

Answer (score 3):

Off topic: Am I the only one who is thinking that uploading a new version each day is an overkill? Are you adding new features each day?

Back on topic: There was a general problem in the market last week.

Have you changed your signing certificate?

Answer (score 2):

If you are following the application upload guidelines properly i.e. managing proper VersionCode and VersionName and app signing with same keystore, than the problem could be at Android Market side.
I have also faced the problem while uploading my app on market i.e. my application is uploaded(update) to the market but the update was not visible till 5 to 7 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to change *anything* in the apk and just hit refresh ~20 times until it works, then this implies the issue is on the server.

If you are trying to send the exact same file twice and it only works once, then the problem is almost guaranteed to be on the server.

BUT

if you change *anything* about the apk, it could be an issue on your side.  If the file name is changed or the version code is changed, then that would most likely be the issue.  Even if the apk is rebuilt between a failed upload and a successful upload, then there are other factors involved and it might not be the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for any empty tags in AndroidManifest.xml ? Its worth to check.